# Qt + opencv for android

Tags: android, c++, qt, opencv

My project is based on Qt (widgets) + Opencv. On Windows I compile it in msvc. In Linux g++.
But with android I have a problem:
Use Windows as a host machine. Install and configure Qt Creator for android. It work fine without opencv library on test project. But then I add a opencv lib in pro file have en errors “Can’t open library”.
Part of test pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\Lib\opencv\build_minGW\include
LIBS += -LC:\Lib\opencv\build_minGW\lib
LIBS += -lopencv_core2410 \
                -lopencv_imgproc2410 \
                -lopencv_highgui2410
```

Opencv library I build by mingw. What I do wrong?

Comment: even so. the question is how to compile opencv for [img]http://SSMaker.ru/3cb91064/ [/img]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to integrate OpenCV into Qt Creator Android project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27562311/how-to-integrate-opencv-into-qt-creator-android-project)

Comment: Read this tutorial: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27562311/how-to-integrate-opencv-into-qt-creator-android-project/39618035#39618035